# running pam_exec script after login complete

Tags: ssh, pam

I'm parsing out the `lastlog` command into a custom file when a user logs in for use with another application that monitors SSH logins.

In `/etc/pam.d/sshd` I have included the line and the very bottom:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/bin/run_on_login.sh
```

This work with one major disadvantage. The script runs BEFORE `/var/log/lastlog` or `/var/log/wtmp` is updated. I presume because a successful login is not considered complete until AFTER the script is being ran.

I tried putting the line in `/etc/pam.d/login` and it seems to make no difference.

Is there a way to run a pam_exec script after the full login process has completed including writing to the logs?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by having the initial `/usr/local/bin/run_on_login.sh` fork another script that runs as a background process, waits a few seconds, then parses the 'last' command.

In example, pam_exec run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/local/bin/run_on_login.sh

nohup /usr/local/bin/parse_last.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Which triggers this scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/local/bin/parse_last.sh

sleep 5

# (truncated for brevity)
last -iF | head -n 50 | awk '{print "something"}'
```